# Notes appearing on all sets in stage manager

Tags: macos, stage-manager

So I changed some sort of setting, and I can't figure out which one. When I turn on Stage Manager on my Mac, my notes windows appear in all sets. Does anyone know how to turn that off - its really annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't test Ventura & whether Stage Manager behaves differently, but this should work on any macOS going way back.
Right click Notes in the Dock > Options & select something other than 'All Desktops'.

Comment: That did it. The caveat here is this - you have to HAVE multiple desktops in order for "All Desktops" to be an option. So if you removed your other desktops, you can't actually turn off that option until you add another desktop again.

Comment: (Will accept answer in 8 minutes since.. apparently I have to wait, for some reason.)

Comment: Ah, Interesting. Didn't actually know that Desktop limitation. I don't think I've had a single Space/Desktop since that feature was first introduced ;))